# Can an artificer use both a shield and a crossbow at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, shield, artificer-infusions

Ok, so from reading the rules, you can't use a shield and a crossbow at the same time due to the fact that you need a free hand to load the crossbow.

My question is about a very niche artificer thing. Artificers have an infusion called Repeating Shot that when placed on a ranged weapon, that weapon ignores the loading feature and loads a magic piece of ammunition when fired.

Would an artificer using a crossbow infused with the Repeating Shot infusion be able to carry a shield with the other hand and benefit from it?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Cade, take the [tour] when you have a moment. Your question has been closed as a duplicate, I believe the linked question should cover your question well, but let us know if it doesn’t, and why it doesn’t, and we can see what needs to be done to make it clearly different.

Comment: Which crossbow were you looking at? It might be relevant (and make it not a dupe)